# Does enabling --web.enable-remote-write-receiver in an Idle Prometheus Increase Memory consumption compared to when the flag is disabled?

Tags: time-series, prometheus, metrics

I'm currently working on configuring Prometheus, and I have a question about the **--web.enable-remote-write-receiver** flag. We are considering enabling this feature in the Prometheus to accept remote writes, but we don't plan to use remote writes at the moment. Instead, we will continue to rely on scraping targets.

I want to understand whether enabling --web.enable-remote-write-receiver without utilizing remote writes and relying solely on scraping might have any notable impact on resource usage or performance.

Could someone shed light on this and provide insights or recommendations?

Thank you in advance for any help.

I checked it locally and I didn't notice any chamnges in the memory consumption